# Delete rows with condition if the first row is -1

Tags: python

Hello i have a data set that i need to sort.
I am sorting it 3 different ways, (Forward fill, Backwards fill and drop")

My code works as is, but i have a problem, i been trying to solve with no luck.

If "forward fill is enabled and the first row is -1, then the drop function should be run.
and if "backwards fill" is enabled and the last row is -1 the the drop function should be run.

I tried alot of if statements but i always get the "the truth value is ambigous" error

```
def load_measurements(filename, fmode):
    RD=pd.read_csv(filename, names=["Year","Month","Day","hour","Minute", "Second", "Zone1", "Zone2", "Zone3", "Zone4"])
    #Forward fill replaces rows with -1 with previous data row
    if fmode =='forward fill':
        if RD.loc[6,0]==-1:
            RD="blah"
        else:    
            RD=RD.replace(-1, np.nan).ffill()

    #Drop deletes all rows if a the data is=-1
    if fmode=="drop":
        RD = RD[RD.Zone2 != -1]
        RD = RD[RD.Zone1 != -1]
        RD = RD[RD.Zone3 != -1]
        RD = RD[RD.Zone4 != -1]
        print(RD)
    #Backward fill replaces rows with -1 with the next data row
    if fmode =='backward fill':
       RD=RD.replace(-1, np.nan).bfill()

    #Splits RD into tvec and data
    tvec=RD.iloc[:, 0:6]
    data=RD.iloc[:,6:]


    return (data, tvec)

print(load_measurements("test.csv", 'forward fill'))
```

Comment: have you an example fo your data .....csv ?

Comment: Yeah sure its a csv file. I dont know how to upload the file, but i made a matching google sheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fC-KVRfQUTh2u0L188HrL-63ver8QDB91UyAsm5LoGw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I sent you a request

Comment: Full error message pls.

Comment: And I sent you a request too.

Comment: Please include the full error message. Where does it occur?

Comment: Thank for the comments.
My problem with my back/forward fill is if the first/last row has a value of -1, then the drop sequence should be run.
I tried things like:
`if fmode =='forward fill':
              for i in range ((RD.shape[1])):
                   if RD.iloc[0,i] == -1
                        fmode="drop"
        else:    
             RD=RD.replace(-1, np.nan).ffill()`
                 
But it says "invalid syntax"
Is there a way to run an if function like this with a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I finally realized you want something like this:
Note, that I relaced `pandas.DataFrame.bfill()` and `pandas.DataFrame.ffill()` as these are aliasses of `pandas.DataFrame.fillna(mode="bfill")` and `pandas.DataFrame.fillna(mode="ffill")` respectively and `bfill()` doesn't gave the required result, I guess it is some bug.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def load_measurements(filename, fmode):
    RD = pd.read_csv(filename, names=["Year","Month","Day","hour","Minute", "Second", "Zone1", "Zone2", "Zone3", "Zone4"], sep=',')
    print(RD)
    RD = RD.replace(-1, np.NaN)

    #Forward fill replaces rows with NaN with previous data row
    if fmode =='forward fill':
        if RD.iloc[0, 6:].isna().sum() == 0:
            RD = RD.fillna(method='ffill')
        else:
            print("\nThere were -1 in the first row!\n")

    #Backward fill replaces rows with NaN with the next data row    
    elif fmode =='backward fill':
        if RD.iloc[-1, 6:].isna().sum() == 0:
            RD = RD.fillna(method='bfill')
        else:
            print("\nThere were -1 in the last row!\n")

    RD = RD.dropna()

    #Splits RD into tvec and data
    tvec=RD.iloc[:, 0:6]
    data=RD.iloc[:, 6:]

    return (data, tvec)

data , twec = load_measurements("test.csv", 'backward fill')
print(data)
print(twec)
```

**Out("forward fill"):**

```
   Year  Month  Day  hour  Minute  Second  Zone1  Zone2  Zone3  Zone4
0  2006      1   15     4       0       0   -1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0
1  2006      2   11     6       1       0    5.0    6.0    1.0    8.0
2  2006      4   21     8       2       0    3.0   -1.0   -1.0    6.0
3  2006      7   14     9       3       0    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0
4  2006     10    2     9       4       0    3.0    2.0    5.0   -1.0

There were -1 in the first row!

   Zone1  Zone2  Zone3  Zone4
1    5.0    6.0    1.0    8.0
3    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0
   Year  Month  Day  hour  Minute  Second
1  2006      2   11     6       1       0
3  2006      7   14     9       3       0
```

**Out("drop"):**

```
   Year  Month  Day  hour  Minute  Second  Zone1  Zone2  Zone3  Zone4
0  2006      1   15     4       0       0   -1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0
1  2006      2   11     6       1       0    5.0    6.0    1.0    8.0
2  2006      4   21     8       2       0    3.0   -1.0   -1.0    6.0
3  2006      7   14     9       3       0    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0
4  2006     10    2     9       4       0    3.0    2.0    5.0   -1.0
   Zone1  Zone2  Zone3  Zone4
1    5.0    6.0    1.0    8.0
3    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0
   Year  Month  Day  hour  Minute  Second
1  2006      2   11     6       1       0
3  2006      7   14     9       3       0
```

**Out("backward fill"):**

```
   Year  Month  Day  hour  Minute  Second  Zone1  Zone2  Zone3  Zone4
0  2006      1   15     4       0       0   -1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0
1  2006      2   11     6       1       0    5.0    6.0    1.0    8.0
2  2006      4   21     8       2       0    3.0   -1.0   -1.0    6.0
3  2006      7   14     9       3       0    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0
4  2006     10    2     9       4       0    3.0    2.0    5.0   -1.0

There were -1 in the last row!

   Zone1  Zone2  Zone3  Zone4
1    5.0    6.0    1.0    8.0
3    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0
   Year  Month  Day  hour  Minute  Second
1  2006      2   11     6       1       0
3  2006      7   14     9       3       0
```

Comment: Thank for the comments.
My problem with my back/forward fill is if the first/last row has a value of -1, then the drop sequence should be run.
I tried things like:

`if fmode =='forward fill':
 for i in range ((RD.shape[1])):
if RD.iloc[0,i] == -1
fmode="drop"
else:
RD=RD.replace(-1, np.nan).ffill()`
                 
But it says "invalid syntax"
Is there a way to run an if function like this with a dataframe?

Comment: @troels If I see you, you don't want np.nan, instead of that you want drop that raw?

Comment: Yeah that is exatly what i want

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding it is almost there.
If there is a np.nan, i want to drop all rows with -1, and if possible print an error message

Comment: Still not there.
There are the three functions: "forward fill", "backward fill" and "drop"
Forward fill takes the next value, unless the first row has a value of -1. Then it should run the drop function.

My problem is making an if statement that looks in the first row for a -1.

Comment: @troels It is an optimized code. True that you don't see any "drop" "if clause", but think it twice: when you pass the "drop" parameter it skip the other two "if clause" and go straight to the `RD = RD.dropna()` line which will do the dropping. So this is the implicit "drop" case. It is because you need this line - the droppping of Nans in both further `bfill` and `ffill` case too and this is only with one code line instead of three. Furthermore the "-1 row" is just another obsolete temporary line. But if you want the less optimized, less pythonic code I can restore that one.

Comment: Im sorry I like the code very mutch,  but I think you misunderstood one of the conditions for the code If fmode is ’forward fill’ and the first row contrains a corrupted measurement or if
fmode is ’backward fill’ and the last row contrains a corrupted measurement, then
delete all rows with corrupted measurements and print a warning.   I hope this makes sense

Comment: @troels Ok, so questions: 1. Define "corrupted measurement" (i.e. NaN or -1, which one?) 2. Define where/when it has to be checked before or after "bfill/ffill" 3. Need we check only one single last/first row?

Comment: 1. Corrupted measurement is -1. 
2. Before "ffill" it should check if the first row has corrupted measurements. if it does all rows with corrupted measurements should be dropped and "ffill" should not be run.
. If the first row doesnt have corrupted measurements the "ffill" function should be run. 
For "bfill" its the same case, but it should check the last row and not the first. 
3. First the last/first row is checked for corrupted measurements to see if the "drop" function should be run. If it doesnt it should run the "bfill"/"ffill"

Hope it makes sense

Comment: @troels check it, please.

Comment: You did it, you're a god damn genious! Thank you!